# Opencv source compile with cuda generates multiple definition link error

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, gpu

I want to build the opencv 3.2 with cuda 8 and I have installed all the required libraries for cuda in my linux system which is a `Debian 9 testing (stretch) 4.9.0-1-amd64`
after generating makefiles with cmake successfully I get multiple definition linkage error by executing make command.
I have tried many configurations with cmake and also I have checked almost all the relating issues in many forums but I couldn't find any solution.
In cmake, I have changed cuda compiler to gcc-5 since cuda 8 needs gcc compiler no later than version 5 and the default gcc compiler is version 6.3
Here is my cmake configuration output:

```
OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo java stitching superres videostab python2 python3
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 viz

  GUI: 
    QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.7.1)
    QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.7.1)
    OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.28)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.7)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.1.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    Aravis SDK:                  NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
    gPhoto2:                     YES

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.3 interface 8006)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
         at:                     /home/user/opencv_build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.3.2)
    Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  YES
    USE NVCUVID:                 NO
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 30 35 37 50 52 60 61
    NVIDIA PTX archs:
    Use fast math:               YES

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                /home/user/git/opencv/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.13)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.13)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.3)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.3)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
    packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.8)
    JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.13)

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       NO
    Performance tests:           NO
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  /usr/local
```

and here is the make command output

```
[ 10%] Built target libwebp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_cudev
[ 14%] Built target opencv_core
[ 14%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so
CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_absdiff_scalar.cu.o:(.bss+0xd090): multiple definition of `cv::cudev::color_cvt_detail::c_RGB2YUVCoeffs_f'
CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_absdiff_mat.cu.o:(.bss+0xd090): first defined here
CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_absdiff_scalar.cu.o:(.bss+0xd070): multiple definition of `cv::cudev::color_cvt_detail::c_RGB2YUVCoeffs_i'
CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_absdiff_mat.cu.o:(.bss+0xd070): first defined here
.....
.....
CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_transpose.cu.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `cv::cudev::color_cvt_detail::c_LabCbrtTab'
CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_absdiff_mat.cu.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/build.make:11685: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.2.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.2.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1204: recipe for target 'modules/cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why do you want to build cudalegacy, it has been troublesome for some time

Comment: unfortunately deselecting cudalegacy does not solve the problem. There are multiple definition link errors yet.

Comment: Try compiling without CUDA support first to narrow down the debugging

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, searching for a solution. PS: Is Qt working with OpenCV? It didn't work for me.

Comment: @Sarvex, without cuda it compiled successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have study many workarounds and finally I came up with a solution to build OpenCV 3.2 with Cuda 8 in Debian 9. There are many unanswered whys with this solution but it actually works:

1-you need gcc compiler versions 5.1 to 5.x.

2-you should install equivalent compiler versions for g++
(you don't need to uninstall your newer compiler versions)

3-The OpenCV itself should be compiled with gcc 5.x so you should choose your gcc and g++ compiler manually in CMAKE

4-the separate compilation option should be disabled from CMAKE
thanks to @InfinityChaos for this offer

5-The pre-compiler option should be disable from CMAKE (very important)

6-you could enable Qt, OpenGL and OpenCl options no problems will occur

7-you don't need to mark TBB option.

Comment: TBB doesn't cause any errors, it can be used. Just don't use `BUILD_TBB`, get a premade TBB package from the internet, and set it there.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, found a *workaround* at last. (Btw, I'm using CMake GUI).

You have to uncheck `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION` in the CMake-GUI options.

Unfortunately, this just a workaround and CUDA separable compilation cannot be used in Linux. (You have to use Windows for this). I found this in a issue(https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5557) in  the OpenCV repository.

**PS:**

I am having trouble building OpenCV with Qt5. If you are successful in doing so, please notify me in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the solution. I have not try it yet. But without CUDA I could compile with qt5. I can't understand why with separate compilation it should fail would you please post the original issue link? Do you think it is worth trying to compile all opencv and CUDA with gcc-5

Comment: I tried to find the issue but couldn't find it again. This is what I did - CUDA 8.0 doesn't compile with GCC 5+, so I had to install GCC 4.9 (I got it from the old debian Jessie), and I set the CUDA host compiler as GCC 4.9 and the rest of OpenCV with GCC 6

Comment: Found the issue atlast, actually the issue is still open -> https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5557